# Probability: Parking Meter question

Tags: probability

I am encountering a problem from Grinstead and Snell’s Introduction to Probability ([https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Eprob/prob/prob.pdf)) where I find myself disagreeing with the solution manual. I am looking from some guidance to see if I am misunderstanding or the solution key is wrong.

### Original question:

> Reese Prosser never puts money in a 10-cent parking meter in Hanover. He
> assumes that there is a probability of .05 that he will be caught. The first
> offense costs nothing, the second costs 2 dollars, and subsequent offenses cost
> 5 dollars each. Under his assumptions, how does the expected cost of parking
> 100 times without paying the meter compare with the cost of paying the meter
> each time?

### Solution is given in manual:

[image]

### My question:

The solution is using a poisson distribution with n=100, p=0.05, so lambda=n*p=5

Looks like it's trying to compute the expected cost by P(n)*TotalTicketCost(n), but I don't think it's right.

> Here are the values for different n,
>
> TotalTicketCost(n=0)=0
>
> TotalTicketCost(n=1)=0
>
> TotalTicketCost(n=2)=2
>
> TotalTicketCost(n=3)=7
>
> So, TotalTicketCost$(n)=5n-8$ for $n\geq2$
>
> P(n) = $\frac{5^n e^{-5}}{n!}$

This is quite different from the solution. Intuitively, I think \$24.9 is quite close to $25, which does not make sense. When you get away for free on the first ticket and a reduced cost on the second ticket, I think that should offset more expected cost than just just a dime.

Am I missing something? What do you guys think?

Comment: In the expression in your book, shouldn't it be $5+2$ and not $5\cdot2$? And $5\cdot(n-1)+2=5\cdot n-3$, instead of $5\cdot n$?

Comment: you are right, i made a mistake, let me correct that part, but I also realized it should be $(5n-8)$

Comment: I think (5+2) will correct part of the expression but it still does not fix the other terms on the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. For brevity write $C(n):=\text{TotalTicketCost}(n):=5n-8$ so the expected cost of never paying the meter is
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty C(n)P(n).$$
This can be evaluated more easily by starting the sum at $n=0$ and then repairing the damage:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C(n)P(n) - C(0)P(0) - C(1)P(1)=E[C(X)] -  C(0)P(0) - C(1)P(1)$$
where $X$ is a Poisson($5$) random variable.

By my calculation I get $E[ C(X)] = 5E(X)-8=17$ and $C(0)P(0)=-8e^{-5}$ and $C(1)P(1)=-15 e^{-5}$, for a total of $17 + 23 e^{-5}\approx 17.15$ (check my work!)

Comment: I ran the math again, looks good to me